# Shortcut for alphanumerical values in regular expressions (Clojure)?

Tags: clojure

Is there a shortcut for alphanumerical values in regular expressions, such that instead of `#"[a-zA-Z0-9]"` you can write something like `#"\alphanum+"`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

```
#"\p{Alnum}" ;; only works for ASCII chars
```

Comment: `\w` is used much more frequently, and is identical except that it also includes the _ character.